# Полнотекстовый поиск (Fulltext search)

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет.

Подскажите, зачем придуман этот поиск? Где его нужно использовать? Как я понял, ограничение его применений велико - только в определенных типах таблиц и типах полей.
Его используют только для сортировки результата в зависимости от точности совпадения?

Практический вопрос:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST('How')";
```

У меня в поле title есть слово How .Почему выборка не происходит. Ошибок нету. Есть такая строка в поле title:

*How To Use MySQL Efficiently*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поиск вообще придуман, чтоб найти результаты по образцу.
FullText поиск - придуман, чтоб найти слово или сочетание в текстовом поле c учетом морфологии.

Преимущества поиска с помощью оператора LIKE:

- незначительное увеличение времени обработки запроса при увеличении его сложности
- возможность сортировки результатов
- универсальность: можно использовать для поиска рпактически по любым типам полей, в отличии от полнотекстового

Недостатки LIKE:

- отсутствие поддержки морфологии
- отсутствие модификаторов
- поиск по всем строкам

Преимущества полнотекстового поиска:

- поддержка морфологии
- выдача результатов по релевантности
- наличие модификаторов, схожих с модификаторами в поске Гугла и Яндекса
- стоп-слова
- возможность настройки

Недостатки:

- отсутствие возможности сортировки
- поддержка только VARCHAR и TEXT полей с индексами FULLTEXT
- ресурсоемкий процесс
- поддержка MyISAM таблиц, вроде как с 5.5 добавлен в InnoDb
- при установленном ключе FULLTEXT добавление данных в таблицу происходи дольше

Для качественного полнотекстного поиска рекомендую использовать sphinx или percona сервер, куда уже встроен сфинкс.